# $scope.$watch for the parent controller using controllerAs syntax

Tags: angularjs, watch

In my angular project I'm trying to watch a property in the parent controller, however I'm using controllerAs syntax and I cannot get hold of it. I used 'controllerAs' syntax for the parent controller and and then declared 'this' to equal 'self' from within the controller object. I also used 'controllerAs' syntax on the child scope but this time declared in-line, instead of in the routing like before, and also set 'self' equal to 'this'.

Any ideas on how to watch the parent property would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would give my controllers separate names and then use:

```
   $scope.$watch("self_parent.property", function() {
       // ...
   });
```

Assuming your parent controller is called self_parent.